# How can I evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\ 1000}(x+k)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I would like to examine the limit of the following function as x goes towards infinity:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\ 1000}(x+k)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}$$

I already have tried to split the sum, exlude the factor $\ x^{10} $ , then reduce the fraction by it in the numerator and denumerator, so that i might see a way to determine the limit. But that does not seem to help me proceeding

And using l’Hospital´s Rule seems to be too complicated.

Comment: Is it not just straightforward to do this by comparing highest order terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the "honest" calculation using properties of limits:

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\ 1000}(x+k)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}
& = & \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\ 1000}\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)^{10}}{1+\frac{10^{10}}{x^{10}}}\\
& \stackrel{x\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} & \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\ 1000}\left(1+0\right)^{10}}{1+0} \\
& = & \sum_{k=1}^{\ 1000} 1 = 1000
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: +1 for the honesty.

Answer (score 6):

Note that every term $x^i$ for $i \leq 10$ does not affect the limit once dividing top and bottom by $x^{10}$. The $x^{10}$ term on the numerator is $1000x^{10}$ and so the limit is $1000$.

Comment: Hm, and how would you show that formally by reshaping the given function?

Comment: @R.K. Note that $(x+k)^10$ has exactly one $x^10$ term, as well as some other lower degree terms. Dividing the numerator and denominator by $x^10$ yields a constant term of $1000$ on the numerator, with some $\frac{1}{x^i}$ terms which tend to zero. On the denomiator a similar thing happens, with a constant term of $1$ with some $\frac{1}{x^i}$ terms which tend to $0$.

Comment: Ok, i see what you meant, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$S_p=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}(x+k)^{10}$$ and use the binomial theorem to get
$$S_p=p x^{10}+5p(p+1)x^9+O(x^8)$$ So
$$\frac{S_p}{x^{10}+\text{anything}}= p+\frac{5p(p+1)} x+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$